# Yii2: uniqueID and id modules properties

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-modules

[Class yii\base\Module](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-module.html) has 2 properties: *id* and *uniqueId*. The former "uniquely identifies this module among other modules which have the same parent", while the latter - just unique id. But I still don't understand the diff. Why need we *id* to identify module, especially from modules with the same parent, if there is *uniqueId*, that identifies module too? It would be nice to show me example, which reveals the need for both these properies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module `id` is the relative ID of a module and when there aren't parent 
the module `id` coincides with the `uniqueId`. but if you use nested module (one or more) within other then comes the need to be able to still assign an identifier of the module (his name). This name is assigned using Id, which corresponds to the entry in `config/main.php`. The need to manage, as part of the framework, the absolute identification of each of these nested modules is instead carried out by `UniqueId`. `UniqueId` is read only because his correct construction is managed by the Framework

Comment: So, u want to say, that `id` is needed for user and `UniqueId` - for framework, right?

Comment: Is some way yes. Id is assigned by you while UniqueId is generated by Yii2 framework.

Comment: But I don’t understand, what do u mean by saying: “The module `id` is the relative ID of a module”. I changed `id` property for nested module (in _config/web.php_ in app) and outputed properties `id` and `uniqueId` in view of this module: the latter have changed too! Please, give me an example, when these 2 properties are NOT the same.

Comment: try building a nested module and echo the id and UniqueId. Eg. user (parent) admin child and the a master only admin.  and try echo the module id and the UniqeID for the first admin is `'user/admin` the secondo is `admin`

Comment: Just a clarification. if you do not use nested modules this type of study is unimportant and of no practical use. in that the two values, (what you assigned to identify the module and the one generated by the framework to avoid ambiguity between the same names in different levels) coincide

Comment: I need nested modules. I have seen `user/admin` (it is `uniqueId`) and `admin` (`id`) - but only with route `r=user/admin`. If route is just `admin`, `id` and `uniqueId` are the same. Thanks for example. **Ps**: as I know, in Yii2 `config/main.php` is absent and `config/web.php` is used instead (I mean your first answer).

Comment: In advanced tempate the configuration is different and is in app/config/main.php . In basic template is like you say